# Why can't I upload the sketch to my Board?

Tags: error-handling, arduino, uploading

I am using Roboduino board, Whenever I am uploading the blink sketch I am getting following errors. I am using the board from quite some days. But problem is occuring from now onwards.

-- I have selected the right board - Arduino Duemilanove or ATmega 328 (With wich I am working from long back)

--I am using correct serial port COM4 (I have removed the cable and reconnected it to confirm the port it is COM4 only.)

--I have removed all connections to the board (pin 0 and pin 1 are free now)

What might be the problem? How to resolve this?

The error I encountered is

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x8d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x8d
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x8d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x8d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x8d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x8d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x8d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x8d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x8d
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x8d
```

Comment: 1. try to manual reset board and suddenly click upload on arduino ide <br> 2. Did you have another board? try to replace mega328p from another to this board. I think bootloader on this mega328p is broken or chip is gone. Because you can see com port when you attach the board to your pc.

Answer (score 0):

this is shitty Arduino clone, i think the board is not getting duely resetted or the connections are bad. try selecting Arduino UNO because the ATmega328p onboard might be using the optiboot bootloader.